Why is pyinstaller failing to freeze just an `import pandas`?
I am trying to freeze a simple Python file that only contains the following content:
import pandas

But I get the following error:
AttributeError: Failed to retrieve attribute __version__ from module dataclasses

I am using the following versions:

pyinstaller: 5.13.2
pandas: 2.2.1
Python: 3.9.7

It is all running on Anaconda and Windows.
This problem started with a bigger file, I have managed to reduce it to this minimal example.
